# wordpress - display parent category of selected one

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I could display the selected category name in the following way:

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) :
    single_cat_title();
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
...
```

The problem is that I cannot display parent category name of selected category as well. Could you please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `get_category_parents()` helper function.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) :
single_cat_title();
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
echo get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' &raquo; ');
?>
```

You would want to do this in the loop, rather than above it.

Comment: thanks for your help. I wrote the code this way:  **<?php echo get_category_parents($cat, FALSE, ' / '); ?>** Could you please help me to get rid of the last  ' / ' ?

Comment: yes it displays **parent / child / **  , but I want it to display **parent / child**

Comment: are you trying to create a breadcrumbs? if so, there is a much easier and more effective way to do this.